# SQL Server stored procedure to store Latest Value and History table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, database-design

Looking for a way to do this is SQL Server

Table 1 - `Status_Latest`

```
DeviceID Status(bit) TimeOfUpdate(datetime)
```

Table 2 - `Status_History`

```
DeviceID Status(bit) TimeOfUpdate(datetime)
```

Looking for the fastest way to implement this:

Stored procedure is called which passes `DeviceID` and status.

If `DeviceID` doesn't exist in `Status_Latest`, insert into both `Status_Latest` and `Status_History`

If value is different than current value in `Status_Latest`, update it 
and store to `Status_History`

I was thinking

Option A: I could select from `Status_Latest` and then update `Status_Latest` and `Status_History` if values are different.

Option B: I could update `Status_Latest` while storing old value?
If values are different update `Status_Latest` and `Status_History`

What I have so far (only gets called on change from application, needs to be handle in DB stored procedure)

```
insert into [SensorStateChange_History] (SensorIndex, SensorOccupied, TimeOfDataBaseStorage)
values (@SensorIndex, @SensorOccupied, GETUTCDATE())

update SensorState_Latest
set SensorOccupied = @SensorOccupied, 
    TimeOfDataBaseStorage = GETUTCDATE()
and SensorIndex = @SensorIndex

if @@ROWCOUNT = 0

insert into SensorState_Latest
values (@SensorIndex, @SensorOccupied, GETUTCDATE())
```

Comment: What is the question here? What you posted should work just fine.

Comment: That stores a value in the table everytime the stored procedure is called. I want the stored procedure to only store history if the value is different then the latest

Comment: Then you just need to add the extra condition to the update.

Comment: what extra condition? to return the previous value?

Comment: Add an extra predicate to the update statement. I assume you mean the value of sensoroccuied? Just add "And SensorOccupied <> @SensorOccupied" or whatever value it is that you want to know if it changed.

Comment: that wouldn't solve the problem. I want to search table 1 to see if the value is different that the value passed in and if it is i want it to add a row to table 2. 

Basically just record in table 2 when the value changes and store the latest value in table 1.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [SensorStateChange_Latest] WHERE SensorIndex=@SensorIndex AND SensorOccupied=@SensorOccupied)
  BEGIN
  update SensorState_Latest
  set SensorOccupied = @SensorOccupied, 
    TimeOfDataBaseStorage = GETUTCDATE()
  WHERE SensorIndex = @SensorIndex;    

  if @@ROWCOUNT = 0    
    insert into SensorState_Latest
    values (@SensorIndex, @SensorOccupied, GETUTCDATE())

  insert into [SensorStateChange_History] (SensorIndex, SensorOccupied, TimeOfDataBaseStorage)
  values (@SensorIndex, @SensorOccupied, GETUTCDATE());

  END
```

Comment: That makes sense. To improve performance, is there a way to to eliminate the first select statement and utilize the update statement to update / retrieve the old value??
Then you don't have to access the database to find the value and then to update it?

Comment: Actually, I believe the IF EXISTS() will perform faster than what you are suggesting.   Google and learn about the EXISTS() function and you will see what I mean about its performance benefits.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/miah/archive/2008/02/17/sql-if-exists-update-else-insert.aspx

I would disagree... if it doesn't exist there is only 1 table scan
if it does exist it has a minimum of 2 table scans.

I guess the question comes down to how can I utilize the update to just always update the latest value and also return its previous value... that would results in a single table scan all the time and access to the previous and current value after the update

Comment: Well, I guess that's a valid academic question, but I'm letting my answer stand as "How I would do it".

Comment: If you really want to minimize your table scans you could do this in a trigger. Then the inserted and deleted virtual tables would have the "before" and "after" values. I would code this like this answer though.